# Changing the background color of matching text in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm, when I double-click on a word, matching words are highlighted in the document by changing their background color.

How to change this background color?

In `Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Search Results`, I see a `Text Search Result` that let me change the background of matches when I do explicit searches, but this does not affect the background color of matching words when I simply double-click on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing `Identifier under caret` setting in `Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General -> Code -> Identifier under caret -> Background`.

This will change behaviour of putting cursor under some identifier.